# MUI Typescript Autocomplete - wrap component to return scalars values of certain property instead of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

when using MUI Autocomplete, the generic value defined in `onChange` / `value` is the interface of the object set in the `options` property.

For example, in an autocomplete with the following:

```
<Autocomplete
      options={top100Films}
      onChange={onChange}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
    />
```

Where `top100Films` has the interface:

```
interface Props {
    id: number;
    label: string
}
```

The `onChange` and `value` properties would have the type of `Props`....which is an object. Now in my form, I'd only like to submit the `id` of the `Props` object. As a result, I would like to have the type of my Autocomplete `value` propery equal `number`.

Therefore, I think we need to wrap the `Autocomplete` so that we can modify the `value` and `onChange` values. My initial thought for this was to do the following:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<number>();

const onChange = useCallback((value: number) => {
    
})

<WrappedAutocomplete 
    valueProp={"id"} // <-- this defines the property that we should be extracting the value from. It's a scalar. Should only be able to select from keys of the Props interface.
    options={top100Films} // <-- nothing changed here, this still has the interface object of Props
    value={value} // <-- assuming this is a controlled form value, this value should match the type of "id", in this case, number.
    onChange={onChange} // <-- other half of controlled component, this should be (value: TypeExtractedFromValueProp) => void;
    {...allTheOtherAutocompleteProps}
/>
```

Also something to note is that `Autocompletes` take a `multiple` attribute. If it is `true` that means that `value` would need to be the `Array` type of the scalar defined by `valueProp`.

Does this issue make sense? Some further reading can be found here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/23708

For those talented with Typescript, I could really use your help on defining the implementation of a `WrappedAutocomplete`!

Comment: Better to show your attempt and let people help with your mistakes. Asking for someone to just hand you a solution is usually not well received here on SO (and also is not in line with the site guidelines, see [ask]).

Comment: cool - added a solution, interested to know if there's a better implementation now though!

Answer (score 3):

Here's my (successful) attempt, please let me know if there's a better implementation. Note, I used `Except` which is essentially `Omit` from `type-fest` but it actually removes the property from the type unlike `Omit`.

I created a new interface to `&` with existing props:

```
interface CustomProps<
    TOption extends Record<keyof TOption, TOption[keyof TOption]>,
    TInternal extends TOption[TProp],
    TProp extends keyof TOption,
    TLabel extends keyof TOption,
    Multiple extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
    DisableClearable extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
    FreeSolo extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
> {
    valueKey: TProp;
    labelKey: TLabel;
    value: AutocompleteValue<TInternal, Multiple, DisableClearable, FreeSolo>;
    onChange: (value: AutocompleteValue<TInternal, Multiple, DisableClearable, FreeSolo>) => void;
    options: TOption[]
}
```

```
function WrappedAutocomplete<
    TOption extends Record<keyof TOption, TOption[keyof TOption]>,
    TInternal extends TOption[TProp],
    TProp extends keyof TOption,
    TLabel extends keyof TOption,
    Multiple extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
    DisableClearable extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
    FreeSolo extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
>({ valueKey, value, labelKey, onChange, ...props }: Except<AutocompleteProps<TInternal, Multiple, DisableClearable, FreeSolo>, "value" | "onChange" | "options"> & CustomProps<TOption, TInternal, TProp, TLabel, Multiple, DisableClearable, FreeSolo>) {

    const options = props.options.map((option) => option[valueKey]);

    return (
        <>
            <Autocomplete
                {...props}
                options={options}
                value={value}
                onChange={(event, value) => {
                    onChange(value)
                }}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => {
                    if (typeof option === "string") {
                        return option;
                    } else {
                        const item = props.options.find((o) => o[valueKey] === option)

                        if (!!item) {
                            return item[labelKey]
                        } else {
                            return "NOT FOUND"
                        }
                    }
                }}
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

So now you can do something like this:

```
<WrappedAutocomplete
                multiple
                options={top100Films}
                valueKey={"id"}
                labelKey={"label"}
                value={value} <--- since multiple is true, this is number[]
                disabled={disabled}
                onChange={(value) => {
                    onChange(value) <-- value is also number[] instead of Props type
                }}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                        {...params}
                        label={label}
                        inputProps={{
                            ...params.inputProps,
                            autoComplete: 'new-password', // disable autocomplete and autofill
                        }}
                        helperText={helperText}
                    />
                )}
            />
```